# Homogeneoused ODE: $x' + 2x + 2x'' + x' = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have 
$$x'+2x+2x'' + x' =0,$$
which goes to

$$x'' + x' + x = 0$$

and I take the characteristic equation...

$$a^2 + a + 1 = 0$$

and this comes out to be $a = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt 3i}{2}$.

Is this right? I have never had such a weird value???

Comment: I think you should get two value of $a$?

Comment: oh woops sorry john, that was meant to be 1 (+-)

Comment: It means your answer has some oscillatory component.

Comment: copper.hat why does it oscillate? how does the i get multiplied by another i to oscillate anyway?

Comment: The solutions will be of the form $t \mapsto e^{at}$. So, in the above example, you will have $t \mapsto e^{- {1 \over 2} t} (\cos ({\sqrt{3}\over 2}t) \pm i \sin ({\sqrt{3}\over 2}t))$. If your initial conditions are real, then the complex parts will cancel out to get a real function.

Comment: oh that is very nice and true, thank you very much copper hat, nice name btw

Comment: Please avoid subjective words such as "hard" in the title of the question. For most users of this site, this ODE is completely trivial...

Comment: @HansLundmark Hard ODE's are a type of ODE where I am from, I think you call them homogeneous like milk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the following ODE:
\begin{align}x' + 2x + 2x'' + x' &=0 \\ \therefore 2x''+2x'+2x&=0 \\ \therefore x''+x'+x&=0 \end{align}
We can find the characteristic equation

\begin{align}a^2 + a +1 &=0\end{align}
Which using the quadratic formula, gives us the following roots
\begin{align}a&= \frac{-1\pm\sqrt{-3}}{2} \\ &=-\frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i\end{align}

Thus our general solution $y$ is given by
\begin{align}y &= e^{-\frac{1}{2}x}\bigg(c_1\cos{(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x)}+c_2\sin{(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x)}\bigg), \  c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb{R}\end{align}

> **Just an extra note:** If the given ODE were to be non-homogeneous, the above solution would only be your complementary solution $y_c$. You would then have to find your particular solution $y_p$ as well and then sum them together as your general solution $y= y_c + y_p$

Comment: oh yes, very beautifique